# how to associated UIViewController in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

As a practice, I rewrite the [TWTSideMenuViewController repository](https://github.com/twotoasters/TWTSideMenuViewController) in Swift. But xcode build failed.
Here is the source code:

```
@implementation UIViewController (TWTSideMenuViewController)

- (void)setSideMenuViewController:(TWTSideMenuViewController *)sideMenuViewController
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(sideMenuViewController), sideMenuViewController, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

- (TWTSideMenuViewController *)sideMenuViewController
{
    TWTSideMenuViewController *sideMenuController = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(sideMenuViewController));
    if (!sideMenuController) {
        sideMenuController = self.parentViewController.sideMenuViewController;
    }
    return sideMenuController;
}

@end
```

here is my code:

```
var key: String = "sideMenuViewController";
extension UIViewController {
    var sideMenuViewController: HXSideMenuViewController {
    get {
        var sideMenuController: AnyObject = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key);
        if (sideMenuController === nil) {
            sideMenuController = self.parentViewController.sideMenuViewController;
        }
        return sideMenuController as HXSideMenuViewController;
    }
    set (sideMenuController) {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, sideMenuController, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN));
    }
    }

}
```

here is the error message:

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

But I tested the following code has not problem:

```
var key: String = "sideMenuViewController";
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, "just for test", UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN));
println(objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key)); // print "just for test"
```

is there some code I write wrong?

Comment: Oh, I don't know swift, help you up

Comment: My code works in Beta 5, but runs into same problem in Beta 6. It's definitely a compiler bug. Just report it and wait for the next Beta release.